# regexp_replace get specific character after single quotes and space

Tags: sql, oracle

I am not that good in regex but I want to catch a specific word after `Info_type`, so the result would be `DATABASE` or `APPLICATION` or `MOBILE` .

example:

```
Flyfast,unix.system,1-1-1,""Table X"" D-Day=""Flood"" id =123123PTIWQ Type='A' info_name=""Fast""  Info_type="""DATABASE""" Starting="10:00:10" Ending=""0000"" Comments="""NONE"""

Flyfast,unix.system,1-1-1,""Table X"" D-Day=""Flood"" id =123123PTIWQ Type='A' info_name=""Fast""  Info_type="""APPLICATION""" Starting="07:00:30" Ending=""0000"" Comments="""NONE"""

Flyfast,unix.system,1-1-1,""Table X"" D-Day=""Flood"" id =123123PTIWQ Type='A' info_name=""Fast""  Info_type="""MOBILE""" Starting="02:00:20" Ending=""0000"" Comments="""NONE"""

Flyfast,unix.system,1-1-1,""Table X"" D-Day=""Flood"" id =123123PTIWQ Type='A' info_name=""Fast""  Info_type="""DATABASE""" Starting="00:00:10" Ending=""0000"" Comments="""NONE"""
```

edit:

I have some other data like this :

```
Flyfast,unix.system,1-1-1,""Table X"" D-Day=""Flood"" id =123123PTIWQ Type='A' info_name=""Fast""  Info_type="""DATABASE A""" Starting="00:00:10" Ending=""0000"" Comments="""NONE"""
```

I tried `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '(.*)(Info_type\=)') FROM TAB1`

Comment: What’s with the triple quotation marks?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I didn't understand , these texts are inserted from the application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to extract the word and I assume it is always surrounded by triple quotation marks

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '^.*Info_type="""([A-Z ]*)""".*', '\1') 
FROM tab1
```

*Update*

This version is more flexible and allows for 1-3 quotation marks around the word

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '^.*Info_type=["]{1,3}([A-Z ]*)["]{1,3}.*', '\1') 
FROM tab1
```

*Update 2*
Allowed for the word to contain space

Comment: not always surrounded by triple quotes, sometimes 1 doublequote, is it possible to get the space after the double quote

Comment: @Baalback What space, do you mean the one before the word 'Spacing'?

Comment: I mean before the word `starting` Note not always there is world starting

Comment: @Baalback You asked one thing and now you're changing the question, if you always want an extra space before or after then add it to the last argument of REGEXP_REPLACE like `'\1 '`to get a trailing space.

Comment: I appreciate your help but I noticed in some of my data contains space for example ""DATABASE A"" how to treat that ? I have large data that's why I didn't notice it

Comment: @Baalback: `[A-Z]*` allows all uppercase letters. If you want to allow other characters, then add them. E.g.: `[A-Za-z0-9 ]*`.

Comment: I want to allow to get spaces [A-Z]* will allow to get spaces ? I am trying it and its selecting spaces. I want  "DATABASE A" @ThorstenKettner

Comment: The [] holds the characters to match so you can add a space to it or any other characters you want to match, [A-Z ]. Maybe it’s time for you to read up on regular expressions